# MySQL Delete Join error

Tags: mysql, join, syntax-error, sql-delete

I have a weird error cropping up in my delete query. I have 2 tables, one holds menu items. Another holds mapping information which maps an activity id in another table to the menu id.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM tbl_menus m 
INNER JOIN tbl_activity_menus am 
    ON m.uid = am.link_id 
WHERE am.activity_id=13
LIMIT 1
```

This works completely fine. It gets the record I want.

However, changing it to a delete query

```
DELETE m.* 
FROM tbl_menus m 
INNER JOIN tbl_activity_menus am 
    ON m.uid = am.link_id 
WHERE am.activity_id=13
LIMIT 1
```

It comes up with: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1'`

Any ideas as to why its not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just use**

```
DELETE m.*
FROM tbl_menus m 
INNER JOIN tbl_activity_menus am 
    ON m.uid = am.link_id 
WHERE am.activity_id=13
```

Comment: That query now comes up with `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN tbl_activity_menus am ON m.uid = am.link_id WHERE am.activity_id'`

Comment: @PhilCross, Updated the answer, added the m.* back and removed the LIMIT keyword.

Comment: Sorry, missed out the fact you removed the limit clause from the query. This now works as expected. Thank you very much for your help, will accept the answer in 4 minutesu (when it allows me!)